# How do I set an array size using command line args[]? Java

Tags: java

The problem I'm running into is that my compiler states that 10 is out of bounds. But how can it be out of bounds if that is the array length i am setting it to?

```
public class InitArray {
   public static void main ( String [] args){

  int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(args[10]); //set array length
  int[] array = new int[arrayLength]; /make array
  int length = args.length; //the array length to be put in for loop
  System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", "Index", "Value");
  for( int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++){
  System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", counter, array[counter]);

   }

}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the compiler is throwing the error or the JVM when you run the application?

Comment: It's not your compiler, it's your running application. How many parameters are you passing to the running application? I'm sure it's less than 10, because you are looking for the 11-th parameter (index 10) and it's not there.

Comment: Oh hi, this is what returns after I run it : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Comment: I should also say that i'm not sure how command line works. I just want to set my array length to 10

Answer (score 2):

You will ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if you don't pass 11 arguments to the program. You are trying to get the integer value of index 10 of args array.

Comment: Thank you :D I'll look into it

Comment: You mean the 11th index. The 1st index is index 0, so the 11th index is index 10.

Answer (score 0):

At what line does it fail? on `Integer.parseInt(args[10])` ?
Does `args.length == 11`?

In your code:
- "`length`" is the number of arguments passed to your program (at least 11 I guess...)
- "`arraylength`" is the value of the 11th arguments, what it's value?

It seems you exchanged `length`and `arraylength` in the `for`loop

Comment: Yes exactly that, Interger.parseInt(args[10]). What i thought was that it would go into arrayLength and set my array to 10